ERROR: Could not create directory for python package installation
I'm trying to install fastchunking as a dependency for another program and I'm getting this string of errors when attempting to install:
$> python.exe -m pip install fastchunking
Collecting fastchunking
  Downloading fastchunking-0.0.3.tar.gz (24 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pybindgen in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from fastchunking) (0.21.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: fastchunking
  Building wheel for fastchunking (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Generating file C:\Users\alexander.been.LC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gu2m0whc\fastchunking_45690b13b00046fcbf5b3e0d96787acf\build\rabinkarprh.cpp
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastchunking
      copying fastchunking\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastchunking
      copying fastchunking\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastchunking
      copying fastchunking\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastchunking
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lib
      copying lib\rabinkarpgen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lib
      copying lib\rabinkarp_gen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lib
      copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lib
      running build_ext
      building 'fastchunking._rabinkarprh' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\alexander.been.LC
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\alexander.been.LC\AppData
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\alexander.been.LC\AppData\Local
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\alexander.been.LC\AppData\Local\Temp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\alexander.been.LC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gu2m0whc
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\alexander.been.LC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gu2m0whc\fastchunking_45690b13b00046fcbf5b3e0d96787acf
      error: could not create 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\alexander.been.LC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gu2m0whc\fastchunking_45690b13b00046fcbf5b3e0d96787acf': The system cannot find the path specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastchunking
  Running setup.py clean for fastchunking
Failed to build fastchunking
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (fastchunking)

I need to install this with python 3.10 because the parent tool requires it. What could be the cause of this?


I need to install this with python 3.10 because the parent tool requires it. What could be the cause of this?

fastchunking 0.0.3 has no support for Python 3.10. It was released long before Python 3.10. However, it currently supports Python :: 3.5 which is way too old.
What parent package requires it as a dependency? You may consider using a maintained package with similar functionality.

Fastchunking is required for pyaff4.

SOLVED!
I was able to download Fastchunking 0.0.3 manually from here and run
python.exe .\setup.py build
python.exe .\setup.py install

using Python 3.10.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
